# How to change background color of a widget on emitted signal

Tags: multithreading, qt

How would I go about changing the background color of a widget in the main thread from a signal emitted from a worker thread. I tried creating a connection from worker thread to main thread as below but it did not work.

```
QObject::connect(workerThread, SIGNAL(changeBgColor()), statusWidget, SLOT(setStyleSheet("background-color:blue")));
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: add `Qt::QueuedConnection`  
QObject::connect(workerThread, SIGNAL(changeBgColor()), statusWidget, SLOT(setStyleSheet("background-color:blue")),Qt::QueuedConnection );

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would call a function to do it:
Depends what version of QT you have but this is the latest way and how I would do it(MainWindow as I do not know your naming):

```
connect(worker, &Worker::sendWidgetChange,this,&MainWindow::receiveWidgetChange);

void MainWindow::receiveWidgetChange(QString color){
     m_myWidget->setStyleSheet("background-color:" + color + ";");
}
```

Your version:

```
QObject::connect(workerThread, SIGNAL(changeBgColor(QString)), statusWidget, SLOT(receiveWidgetChange(QString)));
```

This is not tested for errors...

Comment: My widgets are created with the main function and not within another class called MainWindow. When I first tried doing this I created a function after the main function but compilers would not allow this saying I could not declare functions there. Is there a way I can declare functions in the main.cpp file that have access to the widgets created in main() function? Or is there some other way to created something like a delegate in C# that can accomplish the task?